# Why my $_POST don't work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with inputs like

`<input type="text" name="data4" id="data4" value="">`

A function :

```
 function($data1,$data2,$data3,$data4){
     $query = "UPDATE table1 
               SET data1 = "'.$data1.'", data2 = "'.$data2."' , data3 = "'.$data3.'" , data4 = "'.$data4.'"
     $connexion->exec($query);
}
```

A call of my function :

```
function($data1,$_POST['data2'],$_POST['data3'],$_POST['data4'])
```

The problem is the following : My `$data4` got 0 as value instead of the form value. The others `$data` work well so I really don't understand why my `$data4` do that.

Comment: what is your form submit method?

Comment: The above code looks correct - the mistake must be somewhere else. Could you please add some more code (especially the `<form>`).

Comment: Add the compete form, check that you do not have another field with the same name `data4` below the one you are expecting the data to be posted from.

Comment: When I submit the others data works apart my `$data4` so I don't think my form get an error.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 problems here:

1. Your quotes are wrong, this will give you a fatal parse error (see the other answers).
2. Your `$connexion` variable is undefined in the scope of your function. You would need to send that as a parameter as well.

Apart from that you should probably use a prepared statement to both solve the first problem and to protect yourself from sql injection.

You should also add error handling to your database calls.

Comment: This is the better answer as it also addresses the sql injections risk - here's a [link](http://bit.ly/1FIlUu0) for those who are new to sql injection.

Comment: I tried to change my quotes, nothing change, my `$connexion` variable is defined, I just didn't show it to you

Comment: @HoareauThomas Don't change the quotes, use a prepared statement instead and check all values inside the function.

Comment: I never do that before. It's like a function who check your values compared to the values I expect ?

Comment: @HoareauThomas It depends whether you are using PDO or mysqli, but the statement would look like `UPDATE table1 SET data1 = ?, data2 = ?, data3 = ?, data4 = ?"` and then you bind your variables to the placeholders (the question marks) after that. Just look for prepared statements in combination with what you are using (PDO or mysqli).

Comment: In this case, I use PDO.

Comment: I do this  : `$stmt = $connexion->prepare('UPDATE table1 SET data1= ?,...)` and `$stmt->bindParam($data1,$data2,...)`

Comment: @HoareauThomas You need to check the manual on `bindParam()`.

Comment: I do this : `$stmt = $connexion->prepare($query with :data) $stmt->bindParam(:data,$data) $stmp->execute();` Something should happen after ?

Comment: @HoareauThomas If your problem has shifted to PDO, you should post a new question with the complete PDO code to see what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your query string is not correct - you have to exchange `"'` with `'"` after .`$data2.` in your query - maybe it is just that and the query does not execute correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SET data1 = "'.$data1.'", data2 = "'.$data2."' , data3 = "'.$data3.'" ,
 data4 = "'.$data4.'"
```

to

```
  SET data1 = '".$data1."', data2 = '".$data2."' , data3 = '".$data3."' , 
  data4 = '".$data4."'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in the function

```
 function($data1,$data2,$data3,$data4)
 {

 $query = "UPDATE table1 SET data1 = '".$data1."', data2 = '".$data2."' , data3 = '".$data3."' , data4 = '".$data4."'";

 $connexion->exec($query);

}
```

**Replace `"'` with `'"` and also use `;` in the end of your query.**

Answer (score 0):

Besides that type that the guys pointed out (replace data2 = "'.$data2."' with data2 = "'.$data2.'") you should also try and bind your parameters to the query or sanitize them, protect yourself from sql injection.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php